# how can I extend a progress bar in a AlertDialog(fluent UI)?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, fluent-ui

I would like to implement an `AlertDialog` using Flutter and  [fluent_ui](https://pub.dev/packages/fluent_ui) for Windows. This is a progressive progress bar, so the percentage will change when some of my other code executes. My problem is that the Progress Bar does not extend until the end of the `AlertDialog`. Currently, the progress bar looks like below, set at progress of 50.

[image: Progress bar inside AlertDialog]

Edit: Below is the code I have tried

```
showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return ContentDialog(
          title: Text(title),
          content: const Expanded(
            child: ProgressBar(value: 50, strokeWidth: 10),
          ),
          actions: [
            const SizedBox(),
            Button(
                style: MyButtonStyles.dialogYes(),
                child: const Text('OK', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0)),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                }),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the code you have already tried

Comment: I've added the code to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `Expanded` with `SizedBox` by providing `infinity`/ specific width.
Also, can be use `SizedBox.fromSize`.

```dart
ContentDialog(
  title: Text("title"),
  content: SizedBox(
    width: double.infinity,
    child: ProgressBar(value: 50, strokeWidth: 10),
  ),
```

[image]